# sql select satatement from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select statement that I use to get some data from a magento database from multiple tables and it works just fine.

I tried to add another select column (publisher) from the table catalog_product_flat to the statement but it doesn't work.

Update: by It doesn't work I meant it keep running without output any result.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
SELECT publisher, increment_id AS NumCommande, si.name AS titre, 
        si.sku AS ISBN, so.customer_email AS MailClient, so.status AS Statut, 
        soh.created_at AS DateDeMiseEnTRaitementd 
FROM `catalog_product_flat` cpf, 
     `sales_flat_order_item` si, 
     `sales_flat_order` so, 
     `sales_flat_order_status_history` soh 
WHERE si.sku = cpf.sku 
AND  si.order_id = so.entity_id 
AND soh.parent_id = so.entity_id 
AND so.status = 'processing' 
AND soh.status = 'processing' 
AND si.qty_shipped = 0.000 
AND si.qty_refunded = 0.0000 
AND soh.created_at IN ( 
                        SELECT min( created_at ) 
                        FROM sales_flat_order_status_history 
                        WHERE parent_id = so.entity_id 
                        AND STATUS = 'processing' 
                    )
```

This the original statement

```
SELECT increment_id AS NumCommande, si.name AS titre, si.sku AS ISBN, 
        so.customer_email AS MailClient, so.status AS Statut, 
        soh.created_at AS DateDeMiseEnTRaitementd 
FROM `sales_flat_order_item` si, 
    `sales_flat_order` so, 
    `sales_flat_order_status_history` soh 
WHERE si.order_id = so.entity_id 
AND soh.parent_id = so.entity_id 
AND so.status = 'processing' 
AND soh.status = 'processing' 
AND si.qty_shipped = 0.000 
AND si.qty_refunded = 0.0000 
AND soh.created_at IN ( 
                        SELECT min( created_at ) 
                        FROM sales_flat_order_status_history 
                        WHERE parent_id = so.entity_id 
                        AND STATUS = 'processing' 
                    )
```

I want to get something like :

```
NumCommande|titre|ISBN|MailClient|Status|DateDeMiseEnTraitement|Publisher|
```

Update: I feel really stupid, I just needed to wait a little bit longer.

Comment: ___but it doesn't work___ is not a good enough description of your issue, How does it not work? Are there error messages?

Comment: You may want to include the table alias (`cpf.publisher`) in case there is an ambiguity that mysql can't resolve. As @RiggsFolly pointed out, it is hard to diagnose without knowing what you're seeing. Is there an error message or is the query returning an empty set?

Comment: Sorry, I updated that part.

Comment: "It doesn't work I meant it keep running without output any result" If it's still running, that means it's not done.  All you can do is wait.

Comment: @Eric you were right, the last time I just waited 2 min (the original statement was executed in few secondes). So I followed your advice and waited a bit longer and it works. I feel so stupid. Thanks